Windows DNS server does not resolve an A record, the rest of records in the zone yes
Hello I have a very weird issue where a primary DNS server cannot resolve only one A record contained and registered within the zone. Any other record resolves fine. Deleted/recreated the record to no avail. Never experienced anything like it. Windows  2022 Srv with many zones AD integrated and not. In this case it is a simple primary zone.

error message is the standard:  "Ping request could not find host xxxx.xxx.org. Please check the name and try again."

What about other methods of resolution? Nslookup. There are also debug logging that can be enabled on the server.

@GregAskew nslookup also cannot resolve the record

Does server log anything at that moment?

nothing logged, first time ever I witness something like it
